# Consideration for COVID-caused newbies

Tags: support, homework, asking-questions

Because of the corona virus outbreak, many schools have responded by either closing entirely or sending the students away and allowing them to continue classes remotely. As a result, we may be seeing an increase in the number of questions from people who have no idea of the norms of CS.SE. I'd urge all of us to be gentle when reminding them, say, that we're not a homework-answering site.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!  Well said.  It would be great to have your help explaining to them our norms and what we're looking for in questions, too.